# VNC Crashes right after login

Tags: 20.04, login, lightdm, vnc

While I'm connecting to a pc via VNC it works smoothly but when I'm trying to log in a specific user which I added the user via the Join to domain process the VNC crashes right after, the login worked before but I think the specific user did something with his profile that causes this issue and I cannot see how to figure it out.

I tried to do some terminal commands such as:

```
sudo service lightdm restart 
sudo service x11vnc restart
```

To restart the services but it still won't work.

I tried to reconfigure the lightdm with the command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```